# In SwiftUI, when I have an array of class objects, how to make a UI view to reflect the change of an element's property?

Tags: swiftui

Please see the following code. When I have an array of class objects, how to make the UI view to reflect the change of an element's property? In this case, the change of a stock's last price.

PS1. Must use `class`, not `struct` for Stock.

PS2. There will be more properties in class Stock.

PS3. Is it possible not to introduce a view model class in the middle?

```
class Stock: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    let symbolName: String
    @Published var lastPrice: Double = 0

    init(symbolName: String) {
        self.symbolName = symbolName
    }
        
    func updateLastPrice(_ price: Double) {
        lastPrice = price
    }
}

class StockRepository {
    static let shared = StockRepository()
    
    func getStockOrCreate(symbolName: String) -> Stock {
        if (stocks[symbolName] == nil) {
            let stock = Stock(symbolName: symbolName)
            stocks[symbolName] = stock
        }
        
        return stocks[symbolName]!
    }
    
    private var stocks: [String: Stock] = [:]
}

struct MainListView: View {
    @State private var tableRows : [Stock] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Main List")
            Table(tableRows) {
                TableColumn("Symbol") { row in
                    Text("\(row.symbolName)")
                }
                
                TableColumn("Last") { row in
                    Text("\(row.lastPrice)")
                }
            }
            
            
        }
        .onAppear {
            let stock = StockRepository.shared.getStockOrCreate(symbolName: "QQQ")
            tableRows.append(stock)
            
            // testing code to change a stock's last price
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
                print("change price")
                stock.updateLastPrice(100.20)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help: [Published works for single object but not for array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57302033)