# Image not showing when button is clicked

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to show a checkmark in an HStack if an item has been selected. When I print what items are selected, before and after the button click, it shows the correct values. Does anybody know why it does not the checkmark even though the values are correct?

```
DisclosureGroup {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        
        ForEach(exercise.equipment, id: \.self) { equipmentName in
            
            HStack {
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                    print(viewModel.isSelected)
                    
                    viewModel.addEquipment(exerciseID: exercise.id ?? "", equipmentName: equipmentName)
                    
                    print(viewModel.isSelected)
                    
                }) {
                    HStack {
                        
                        Text(equipmentName)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
//THIS CODE HERE SHOULD SHOW A CHECKMARK IF EQUIPMENTNAME IS CLICKED
                        if let isSelected = viewModel.isSelected[exercise.id ?? ""], isSelected.contains(equipmentName) {
                            
                            Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
} label: {
    
    HStack {
        Text(exercise.name)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
        
        Text(exercise.muscleGroup)
            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the ```isSelected``` status is buried somewhere in an array in your view model. If you want the view to change as soon as the flag is changed then the view either needs a direct binding to the flag, or it needs to be observing an ```ObservableObject``` which is publishing the flag. If the flag is inside an array then this may be the problem - see [Published works for single object but not for array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57302033/20386264). For more help than this, please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @BenzyNeez isSelected is `@Published var isSelected: [String: [String]] = [:]` which resides in the view model. Should it not update when equipment is selected?

Comment: A change is only published if the complete array is replaced. If you change an item inside the array, this does not get published. Maybe you need to be using an array of ```ObservableObject``` instead, so that you can observe the object that is specific to the exercise. Or even have an ObservableObject specific to the equipment. Either way, you probably need more granularity in your model.

Comment: @BenzyNeez Not exactly true. A @Published property sends change notifications when its _value_ changes. If this "value" is a class instance, the instance (aka reference, means _another_ class instance) needs to change. If the value is an `Array` or `Dictionary`, it sends change notifications whenever an item from the array or dictionary changes, or its size or order of the items (when an array). The logic is based in Equality of the _value_.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Thank you! I discovered to my own surprise that changes within the set were being published so I added an answer that seems to work. But personally, I would avoid using ```@Published``` on an array or set because it doesn't always behave as you might expect. Or at least... as I expect :)

Comment: @BenzyNeez Hopefully, it does!   :) Otherwise, there's either something horrible wrong in the underlying system libraries, or there is some issue in our code. Guess where!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it might depend, how you are updating your view model.

I found it worked with an implementation like this:

```swift
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isSelected: [String: [String]] = [:]

    func addEquipment(exerciseID: String, equipmentName: String) {
        var updatedEquipment = [String](isSelected[exerciseID] ?? [])
        if !updatedEquipment.contains(equipmentName) {
            updatedEquipment.append(equipmentName)
            isSelected[exerciseID] = updatedEquipment
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, your view needs to be observing the model:

- if it is created in the same view then it should have the attribute `@StateObject`
- otherwise, if it is passed to the view then it should have the attribute `@ObservedObject`